# mock function called actual function

Tags: python, cassandra, mocking, python-unittest

I have code for cassandra python driver.

```
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

def sync_my_tables():
    print sync_table
    print "*" * 80
    sync_table(my_models.student)
```

When I try to write UT for this, i mocked `sync_table` using `@patch`.

```
from unittest import TestCase

from mock import patch


class TestCassandraSetup(TestCase):
    @patch('cassandra.cqlengine.management.sync_table', return_value=True)
    def test_sync_my_tables(self, _):
        from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table
        print "*"*80
        print sync_table
        print "*"*80
        cass_setup.sync_my_tables()
```

After `patch`, it call actual function and give error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/venv/tests/test_cassandra_setup.py", line 26, in test_sync_database_tables
    cassandra_client.sync_database_tables()
  File "/venv/code/cass_setup.py", line 18, in sync_my_tables
    sync_table(my_tables.student)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/management.py", line 200, in sync_table
    cluster = get_cluster()
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 182, in get_cluster
    raise CQLEngineException("%s.cluster is not configured. Call one of the setup or default functions first." % __name__)
CQLEngineException: cassandra.cqlengine.connection.cluster is not configured. Call one of the setup or default functions first.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
********************************************************************************
<MagicMock name='sync_table' id='4490003152'>
********************************************************************************
<function sync_table at 0x10b8075f0>
********************************************************************************
```

In print statement, it print `MagicMock` first time, but when print same in actual code, it print actual function not mocked object.

Whey it change in between ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using patch you need to patch the object where it is used. So if `sync_my_tables` is located in a file with a path of `foo/bar/baz.py` you will need to call patch like this:

```
@patch('foo.bar.baz.sync_table')
def test_sync_table(self, _):
    # test code
```

Answer (score 1):

Python cannot mock (replace) things that are already in the module scope. Once imported, you cannot change it from the outside. To make the code testable, you need to import the higher level module and use the method from there as then it becomes just a property that can be changed.

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import management

def sync_my_tables():
    print management.sync_table
    print "*" * 80
    management.sync_table(my_models.student)
```

This way mock is capable of replacing function at runtime (just does `management.sync_table = MagicMock()`).

---

In your test function, you are doing the import after the function has been replaced so it works as expected.