# Python mock not applied to object under test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, magicmock

I am attempting to mock an object to perform some testing

**test.py**

```
@patch("api.configuration.client.get_configuration")
def test(mock_client_get_configuration):
    mock_client_get_configuration.return_value = "123"

    result = code_under_test()

    assert result
```

Inside `code_under_test()` I make the concrete call to `get_configuration()`.

**code.py**

```
from api.configuration.client import get_configuration

def code_under_test():
    config = get_configuration("a", "b")
```

However, whenever I run my test, `get_configuration` is always the concrete version and not my mock.

If I add a print in my test, I can see that `mock_client_get_configuration` is a MagicMock.

If I add a print inside `code_under_test`, then `get_configuration` is always the actual `<function....` and not my mock.

I feel somewhere I am going wrong in how I create my mock. Perhaps it is because my mock does not mimic the two parameters needed on the concrete call so the signature is incorrect?

I'm using Python 3.9 and pytest 7.0.1.

Comment: Similar here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824374/mock-function-called-actual-function

Comment: You need `@patch("yourmodule.code.get_configuration")`, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).